# Populating a ListView with SQLite - ListView appends rows but doesn't show text

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview

I'm trying to populate a ListView with SQLite items. After reading about this here and in other tutorials/examples I tried the following code, but I can't spot where exactly is the issue with it, since it's not working as intended, ListView isn't showing any items. My database has only one type of data, a string called `sentence`. Any help that could at least point me a direction in solving the issue is appreciated.

First I made a `FavoritesDataBaseCore.java`:

```
package com.easyprojects.artgames;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

/**
 * Created by Vinicius on 19/05/2017.
 */

public class FavoritesDataBaseCore extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Favorites.db";

    public FavoritesDataBaseCore(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table favorite(_id integer primary key autoincrement, sentence text not null)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("drop table if exists favorite");
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

The `sentence` is supposed to be added through a button click in `CharacterActivity.java`, relevant code:

```
ImageButton setFavoriteBtn;
private SQLiteDatabase database;
FavoritesDataBaseCore helper;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_character);
    setFavoriteBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.setFavoriteBtnId);
    setFavoriteBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    // Database stuff
    helper = new FavoritesDataBaseCore(this);
    database = helper.getWritableDatabase();
}

// Code below is inside public void onClick(View view)

case R.id.setFavoriteBtnId:
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("sentence", characterTV.getText().toString());
    database.insert("favorite", null, values);
    // A Toast here showing values.toString() works well
    break;
```

And finally the Activity that contains the ListView and creates the `Cursor`, I suspect the problem is here, since the `Cursor` is a major responsable for setting a correct adapter to the ListView, `FavoritesActivity.java`, relevant code:

```
private SQLiteDatabase database;
FavoritesDataBaseCore helper;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_favorites);

    helper = new FavoritesDataBaseCore(this);
    database = helper.getReadableDatabase();
    String[] field = {"sentence"};
    int[] to = new int[]{R.id.SentenceAd};

    Cursor cursor = getData();
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cursor, field, to, 0);

    final ListView FavoritesListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listviewID);  // ListView
    FavoritesListView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

public Cursor getData(){
    Cursor cursor;
    String[] field = {"sentence"};
    cursor = database.query("favorite",null,null,null,null,null,null);

    return cursor;
}
```

My `database_adapter.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/SentenceAd"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Edit:** After adapting the code with @MikeT's suggestions I've come to the conclusion my ListView is appending rows each time I add a value into the database, but `sentence` is never shown in those rows.

Comment: I think your issue could be that you must have _id for the cursorAdapter to work. try changing `cursor = database.query("favorite",field,null,null,null,null,null);` to `cursor = database.query("favorite",null,null,null,null,null,null);`. i.e. **null** as the 2nd parameter which effectively means get all columns. P.S. cursor will never be nullm rather use `cursor.getCount()` to get the number of rows in the cursor. However, don't even move the cursor the adapter will handle positioning. Also DO NOT close the database, that will close the cursor.

Comment: Are u sure ur cursor getting any data from table?

Comment: @MikeT Passing `null` to 2nd parameter doesn't make it work, unfortunately. I'll try deleting the `if` condition then.
@LokeshDesai Sorry, but how can I make sure of that? A simple `Log.d()`?

Comment: `Log.d("CSRCNT", "Cursor Rows=" + Integer.toString(cursor.getCount()));` or place a breakpoint at database.close(). Will allow you to see how many rows the cursor has.

Comment: @MikeT I think that might not be needed, please check my question edit.

Comment: @MikeT As expected since it's appending rows: `D/CSRCNT: Cursor Rows=23`

Comment: Next test would be to see if there is any data add this after extracting the curos. `while(cursor.moveToNext) { Log.d("CSRDATA","id-" + cursor.getString(0) + "sentence= + cursor.getString(1)); }` (assuming I've typed it OK)

Comment: Just noticed `final ListView .....` I don't think it should be final.

Comment: @MikeT Apparently all sentences are there, `05-25 04:19:05.706 8221-8221/com.easyprojects.artgames D/CSRDATA: id-1sentence=She is cool
05-25 04:19:05.706 8221-8221/com.easyprojects.artgames D/CSRDATA: id-2sentence=He is cool
05-25 04:19:05.706 8221-8221/com.easyprojects.artgames D/CSRDATA: id-3sentence=I am cool` and so on till id-27

Comment: @MikeT and I just removed `final`, still not showing. I wonder if this has to do with the XML File

Comment: I've never actually used SimpleCursor however you appear to be passing the id of the TextView that you have defined (SentenceAd). However what the simple cursor is expecting is **IT'S** Textview (i.e. the one it knows about in it's layout). This should be TextView1. So try changing `int[] to = new int[]{R.id.SentenceAd};` to **`int[] to = new int[]{android.R.id.text1};`**. Personally I have always used customAdpaters. re final, I'm not at all sure how that would affect things, if at all.

Comment: @MikeT Exactly!! That solved the issue, and thats a pretty good explanation. If you can please submit this as an answer I'll be glad to accept it!

Comment: Will do. PS. I think you could also have changed `SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cursor, field, to, 0);` to SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.database_adapter, cursor, field, to, 0); (i.e your layout)

Comment: This works as well, and it's even better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of issues. The first few are related to the creation of the **Cursor** in preparation for it's use by the SimpleCursorAdapter. Then there is an issue with how the **SimpleCursorAdpater** has been instantiated/ssetup.

**The Cursor.**

Cursor adpaters require that a column named **_id** exists. To overcome this issue the cursor should include both columns. The easiest way to accomplish this is to use **null** as the 2nd parameter to the query method.

Change

```
cursor = database.query("favorite",field,null,null,null,null,null);
```

to

```
cursor = database.query("favorite",null,null,null,null,null,null);
```

A Cursor returned from the query method will not be null (`cusror.getCount()` is how you would check for no rows), so there is no need or use checking if it is null. Additionally the **Cursor Adpater** (simple or custom) will do the necessary cursor navigation. There is no need to move the cursor. The original has been edited accordingly so no change is required.

Last in regard to the Cursor, closing the Database would close the Cursor (again already edited).

**The SimpleCursorAdapter**

The issue is that you are using a supplied layout as in **`android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`** (the 2nd parameter) this expects you to signify which Cursor column (you have signified sentence) will be displayed in **it's specific TextView** but you have provided a TextView in your own layout.

Changing

```
int[] to = new int[]{R.id.SentenceAd};
```

to

```
int[] to = new int[]{android.R.id.text1};
```

Is one way to resolve the problem, but it's a waste your time and effort in creating you own layout.

To utilise your own layout then **don't** make the above change (as you will want the id of the TextView in your layout) but instead change

```
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cursor, field, to, 0);
```

to use your layout

```
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.database_adapter, cursor, field, to, 0);
```

In short the 2nd (*The layout to be used*) and the 4th (*The Column from the Cursor, by name*) and 5th (The ID of the TextView within the layout where the data from the column will be placed) parameters are interdependent/reliant upon each other.

Comment: Now it's time to change it all to use a CsutomAdapter :) Only kidding :)